# Reverse engineer a ARM-v7a function

Tags: arm, java

Currently I am trying to reverse engineer the following armeabi-v7a function:

[image]

I already wrote the following Java code:

```
 static double getFunc(double param0, double param1, double param2, double param3) {
      double r3, s7, s8, d4, d5, d6, d7, s10, s12, s13, s14, s15;
      s14 = 100.0;
      r3 = param3 - 0xAA;
      s13 = param0;
      s15 = param2;
      s8 = 4.0;
      s7 = param3;
      s10 = 7.0;
      s13 = s13  /s14;

      if (param1 == 1) {
          s13 = s15 *s13;
          s15 = s13 * s8;
          d4 = 0.22;
          s10 = s15 / s10;
          d5 = s10;
          d4 = d5 * d4;
          d5 = 0.6;
          s12 = s7 / s14;
          d5 = d4 * d5;
          s10 = d5;
          s12 = s10 + s12;
      } else {
          s15 = s15 * s13;
          d6 = 0.34;
          s15 = s15 * s8;
          s10 = s15 / s10;
          d5 = s10;
          d5 = d5 * d6;
          d6 = 0.45;
          d6 = d5 * d6;
          s15 = d6;
          s12 = s7 / s14;
          s12 = s15 + s12;
      }

      s14 = 10.0;
      s14 = s12 * s14;
      d6 = 0.5;
      d7 = s14;
      d7 = d7 + d6;
      s14 = d7;
      d6 = 10.0;
      d7 = s14;
      d7 = d7 / d6;

      return d7;
  }
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the correct result. I am doing something wrong but I am a little bit stuck.

It might be that I don't understand the parameter handling on the armeabi-v7a assembly. Do I get it right in the code? Is R3 the third parameter? Are R# always integer values or could it be also double values?
Is the VCVT.F32.F64 important for the Java implementation? If yes, how do I handle them correctly?
R0 is the return register?

It would be awesome if somebody could review my code.

edit: the dissassembly code as requested:

```
getFunc       proc

             VLDR    S14, gvar_1318 
             SUBS    R3, #AAh
             CMP     R1, #1h
             VMOV    S13, R0
             VMOV    S15, R2
             VMOV.F32 S8, #4.000000E+00
             VMOV    S7, R3
             VMOV.F32 S10, #7.000000E+00
             VDIV.F32 S13, S13, S14
             BNE     loc 1294
             VMUL.F32 S13, S15, S13
             VMUL.F32 S15, S13, S8
             VLDR    D4, gvar_12F8
             VDIV.F32 S10, S15, S10
             VCVT.F64.F32 D5, S10 
             VCVT.F32.S32 S7, S7 
             VMUL.F64 D4, D5, D4 
             VLDR    D5, gvar_1300 
             VDIV.F32 S12, S7, S14 
             VMUL.F64 D5, D4, D5 
             VCVT.F32.F64 S10, D5 
             VADD.F32 S12, S10, S12
             B        loc_12C4
loc_1294:
             VMUL.F32 S15, S15, S13 
             VLDR    D6, gvar 1308 
             VMUL.F32 S15, S15, S8 
             VDIV.F32 S10, S15, S10 
             VCVT.F64.F32 D5, S10
             VMUL.F64 D5, D5, D6 
             VLDR    D6, gvar_1310 
             VMUL.F64 D6, D5, D6 
             VCVT.F32.S32 S7, S7 
             VCVT.F32.F64 S15, D6 
             VDIV.F32 S12, S7, S14 
             VADD.F32 S12, S15, S12
loc_12C4:
             VMOV.F32 S14, #1.000000E+01 
             VMUL.F32 S14, S12, S14 
             VMOV.F64 D6, #5.000000E-01 
             VCVT.F64.F32 D7, S14 
             VADD.F64 D7, D7, D6 
             VCVT.S32.F64 S14, D7 
             VMOV.F64 D6, #1.000000E+01 
             VCVT.F64.S32 D7, S14 
             VDIV.F64 D7, D7, D6 
             VCVT.F32.F64 S15, D7
             VMOV    R0, S15
             BX      LR

getFunc        endp


LOAD.text:000012F2           db 0, BFh, AFh, F3h, 0, 80h 
LOAD.text:000012F8 gvar_12F8 dq 3FCC28F5C28F5C29h
LOAD.text:00001300 gvar_1300 dq 3FE3333340000000h 
LOAD.text:00001308 gvar_1308 dq 3FD5C28F5C28F5C3h 
LOAD.text:00001310 gvar_1310 dq 3FDCCCCCC0000000h 
LOAD.text:00001318 gvar_1318 dd 42C80000h
LOAD.text:0000131C           db AFh, F3h, 0, 80h
```

Comment: Can you please paste disassembly as text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I paste the disassembly in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the error.

I incorrectly translated the assembly `SUBS    R3, #AAh` into `r3 = param3 - 0xAA;` but it should be `param3 = param3 - 0xAA;`

Could an expert confirm my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following line is wrong:

```
if (param == 1)
```

I think it should be

```
if (param != 1)
```

BNE branches if Z==0.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, that was not the problem. I tested it with both conditions.

Comment: But you posted only the wrong one..

Comment: Yes but I tested the function with param = 1 and param = 0 but still I get the wrong output.

Comment: Don't worry. Couldn't you step-wise compare the values in the assembler with the ones in your "assembly-like" Java code?